# How to improve image output from montage in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, montage

I joined images using [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/), but the resolution of the image output is less than that of the image's input.

My image's input have dimensions of 640x480 each

[image]

But the output that I get was 256x378

[image]

I was searching in the web and couldn't find a solution to improve the output's image quality.

**The montage command that I'm using**

```
montage -tile 2x3 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png -resize 1024x1024  montage_png.png
```

Anyone know how can I get better output resolution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Suggestion 1**

Try it this way... let `montage` organise the images into a montage and then pass the result on to `convert` to do the resizing of the result.

```
montage -tile 2x3 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png miff:- | convert miff:- -resize 1024x1024 montage.png
```

The intermediate image is passed as a MIFF (Magick Image File Format) which preserves all detail and metadata and quality.

**Suggestion 2**

If it is always just 5 or 6 images and not hundreds, you can also do it all in one go with `convert` like this. All you need to know is that `+append` joins images in a row and `-append` joins images in a column. So I am joining 1&2 in a row, 3&4 in a row, 5 & 6 in a row and then putting the three rows in a stack and resizing the result.

```
convert [12].png +append \( [34].png +append \) \( [56].png +append \) -append -resize 1024x1024 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Lot of thanks! The first method produce the same problem, but the second work perfectly...

Comment: Need `-mode concatenate` in the first approach or the OP's attempt.

Answer (score 26):

Set the mode of operation style (`-mode`) to the `concatenate` value ([as in the documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#mode)).

For example:

```
montage -mode concatenate file1.jpg file2.jpg output.jpg
```

Comment: worked just fine for me! `montage *.jpg -mode concatenate -tile 4x5 MONTAGE.jpg`

Comment: But if you run it a second time, what happens?  See my answer below:

Answer (score 7):

Montage is simple to use like so:

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 2x3 *.png -resize 1024x1024 outfile.png
```

But if you run it a second time this command will also include outfile.png as part of the new montage, of course.

---

Montage is smart enough to change formats properly, so the command can be changed to:

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 2x3 *.png -resize 1024x1024 outfile.jpg
```

Which results in a file that is 2048 pixels wide.

---

If the input files are they are all of uniform size, the simplest way is to use it like so:

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 2x3 *.jpg outfile.jpg
```

---

**To the point of the question:**

In `gnuplot` with the `png` terminal the default canvas size is 640x480, so  a 2x3 montage to a proper `JPG` results in a file that is 1280 pixels wide.

Displayed on a web page that is too wide to print.  Print boundaries are roughly 640 pixels wide (depending on how the margins are set), so it will usually work well with:

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 2x3 -resize 320x240 *.png outfile.jpg
```

Using 320x240 preserves the aspect ratio of the original plot.

Forcing it to be square should be done in the `set terminal` command inside  `gnuplot` if that is the desired outcome.

Best practice for image post-processing is to avoid distorting the image beyond the intent of the program which generates the originals.

Comment: This was the best solution for me. `montage -mode concatenate -tile 3x2 *.jpg -transpose -resize 1920x1080 montage.jpg`